# Несоответствие кодировок в wordpress

Tags: кодировка, wordpress

Доброго времени суток. В вордпрес пытаюсь вывести отдельную страницу активации и выводить её с помощью fancybox при помощи `wp_login_form();`. Но выпадаю  на несоответствие кодировок, собственно, вот код:

```
  <div>

                    <?php $args = array(
                        'echo' => true,
                        'redirect' => home_url(), 
                        'form_id' => 'loginform',
                        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
                        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
                        'id_username' => 'user_login',
                        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
                        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
                        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
                        'remember' => true,
                        'value_username' => NULL,
                        'value_remember' => true 
                    );
                    wp_login_form( $args );?>
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Забыли пароль?</a></br>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>//wp-login.php?action=register">Зарегистрироваться</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Но то, что написано мною здесь, а именно:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Забыли пароль?</a></br>
```

и

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>//wp-login.php?action=register">Зарегистрироваться</a>
```

отображаются нормально. А вот то, что автоматически формируется wordpress в форме, отображается, как не распознанный  юникод.

Вот собственно картинка:

[image]

Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить почему? Все документы в кодировке utf-8 без BOM.

Comment: Надо прописать `<meta charset="utf-8">` в `<head>` или напрямую отдавать заголовок `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все исправил путем внесение изменений в сами файлы админки. И поскольку это была регистрация и авторизация  в wp-login.php. Хотя думаю что проблема в файлах словарей.

Comment: у меня такая же поблема, можете описать, плз, в каких файлах и какие вносили изменения?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress использует Win-1251?

Почитай http://maxsite.org/page/o-kodirovke-wordpress

Comment: Я где-то написал про win-1251 использовал? Вроде написал, что все документы в кодировке utf-8 без bom.